# angular- $interval from user value

Tags: angularjs

I am taking date and time from the user input and

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model= "datetime" name="datetime" min="2016-01-01T00:00:00" max="2116-12-31T00:00:00" class="b" required/>
```

want to appear it in this div `<div ng-bind="x.todoTime| date : 'medium'" class="bb"></div>`                                                               but with the interval of 1000.How should I do it?

Js code:-

```
var app =angular.module('toDolist', []);
app.controller("toDoCtrl",function($scope, $interval) { 
$scope.todoWork = [];

    $scope.todoAdd = function() {      
$scope.todoWork.push({todoText:$scope.task,todoDesc:$scope.description,todoTime:$scope.datetime,todoPriority:$scope.priority,done:false});
            $scope.task ='';
            $scope.description ='';
            $scope.datetime ='';
            $scope.priority ='';
        };
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.datetime;;
      },1000);
```

Comment: You want to show user input with interval of 1000. Can you explain in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

Date: <input type="datetime-local" ng-model="datetime"  min="2016-01-01T00:00:00" max="2116-12-31T00:00:00" id="myLocalDate" value="2014-11-16T15:00:33" ng-change="changeTimer()">
<h1 ng-bind="timerModel"></h1>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    var tt;
    $scope.datetime= "";
    $scope.changeTimer = function(){
            $interval.cancel(tt);
            var t= angular.copy($scope.datetime);
            tt= $interval(function(){
 t.setSeconds((new Date(t)).getSeconds()+1);
                    $scope.timerModel=angular.copy(t);

                    }, 1000);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But it is not going to repeat at every interval

Comment: Also I want that value to change at every second not the div.

Comment: i can help you but pls clarify first: As i understand - You have an input field of type datetime local. The value in this input field has to be shown in a div with a delay of 1 second. Then the value in div will start a clock from the selected value and will be updated every 1 second. Is this your requirement?

Comment: yes @ Vishal Gulati also I want it as a timer  like when the value user input the value and that time passes I want another evnt to happen

Comment: thankyou for the reply. But the timer should be in reverse order. It should be a timer when reaches to 0 another event happened.

Comment: not able to exactly get what item hours/mins/seconds you want to control the value 0 with but hope you can now build upon my answer to achieve.

Comment: I am making a  TO DO LIST app. In which, Reminders with an expired ‘do by’ date should be indicated such (strikeout or color). SO, I need the time user input for do-by date will run in interval of 1 second(in reverse order) and when that time expires it is indicated through (strikeout or color).